# Why does std::atomic<T>::compare_exchange_* should not suffer from ABA issue?

Tags: c++, multithreading, atomic, lock-free, compare-and-swap

In some forums and books (i.e. *C++ Concurrency in Action*) there's a nice example of multi-producer/multi-consumer stack, and in *pop* implementations they usually do the following:

```
// head is an std::atomic<node*> variable
node *old_head = head.load();
while(old_head && !head.compare_exchange_weak(old_head, old_head->next));
...
```

Why would using a *std::atomic<T>::compare_exchange_** prevent the ABA issue?
Let's say that:

- *old_head->next* gets *resolved* before the thread is pre-empted (just before *compare_exchange_weak*)
- then the BA scenario happens
- after the thread is resumed *head == old_head* is valid; in this case *old_head->next* wouldn't be *resolved* again, pointing to an invalid memory location
- the *compare_exchange_weak* would be executed, would pass, but the value *old_head->next* would still be the *old* one

ABA related issue would then happen.

I believe I'm missing something. What am I missing here?

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you would suffer from an ABA problem here.

Though, I think that wouldn't matter because the implementation you are referring to(listing 7.3 in CiA) is anyway invalid, it is leaking nodes.

If we have a look at the most simple reference-counted implementation, the one using a lock-free `std::shared_ptr`(listing 7.9 in CiA) we see that the problem wouldn't happen. When using shared pointers, the old_head would not be deleted as our thread still holds a reference to it, as such a newly created head couldn't be created in the memory address of the old head.

There is also a thread on the official [Concurrency in Action Manning forums](http://www.manning-sandbox.com/thread.jspa?messageID=107159&#107159) about ABA problems in the stack implementation.

Comment: Darn, I know that implementation leaks and whatnot, but reading at the end of the chapter there's a paragraph stating that _all_ the examples in this chapter don't suffer by ABA issue. I'm speechless, they should be more careful... I've wasted hours trying to find why I was wrong in seeing the ABA issue, but I was right... honestly I'm a bit disappointed with the book's author and reviewers (if any).